# Only get back a few properties using Google drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to use google drive API (v3) to get the info of a file like this `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/foobar`.

However, in the response I only got four properties of the file: `kind`, `id`, `name`, `mime_type`.

According to the doc of google drive api I should got a lot back (e.g. owner, url)

Any idea why?

Comment: the answer below is correct,  but please learn to do some research. This question has been asked many times already.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/query-parameters  The assumption is that devs will read all of the documentation, not just bits of it. PS, you should probably accept the answer

Comment: @pinoyyid, yeah I tried to research but if the same question has REALLY been asked many times, then I'm pretty sure the question itself is quite hard to be searched for, otherwise everyone else would find the first question and stop asking again, right

Comment: @pinoyyid ok, maybe we are not desired developers for google apis haha. Thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to retrieve owner and url, you can retrieve the data using `fields` as a query parameter.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/### file id ###?fields=owners,webViewLink
```

If you want to try this using curl, you can use following curl code.

```
curl -G -H \
  "Authorization: Bearer ### your access token ###" \
  -d "fields=owners,webViewLink" \
  "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1### file id ###"
```

The detail information is https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files and https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/query-parameters

Comment: @pinoyyid Thank you for your support.